# How to import handsontable in vue 3 project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, handsontable

i want to use handsontable librairies in my Vue 3 project but i can't even import it.
I followed every step off their doc but i can't find for Vue 3.
I installed it with npm as they said but it seems that it can't find the module.
there is my code :

````
  <div>
    <div id="example1">
      <hot-table :settings="hotSettings"></hot-table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { HotTable } from "@handsontable/vue";

import Handsontable from "handsontable";
// import "handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css";
export default {
  components: {
    HotTable,
    // Handsontable,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      hotSettings: {
        data: Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(6, 10),
        colHeaders: true,
        height: "auto",
        licenseKey: "non-commercial-and-evaluation",
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {},
};
</script>

<style></style> ```

And the error i got :
vue-router.esm-bundler.js?6c02:3264 TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
    at _inherits (vue-handsontable.js?3c78:97)
    at eval (vue-handsontable.js?3c78:1327)
    at Module.eval (vue-handsontable.js?3c78:1690)
    at eval (vue-handsontable.js:1728)
    at Module../node_modules/@handsontable/vue/es/vue-handsontable.js (4.js:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (test.vue?2762:10)
    at Module../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/index.js?!./src/views/test.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (4.js:23)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)

[img error][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZijFZ.png

Thanks !
````

Comment: What is the error

Comment: My understanding -- possibly incomplete -- is that vueJS 3 is re-written in TypeScript.  Meanwhile, the docs (https://handsontable.com/docs) for HOT only indicate support for vueJS 2.  I am suspicious you are running into a language mis-match issue.